# Making a Parentheses program? I'm stuck

Tags: python, loops, recursion, input, parentheses

This is Python. I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for a string input without using global variables. If the string has parentheses only side by side, then it's even. if it has letters, numbers, or the parentheses are spaced out, then it's uneven. For example, () and ()() and (()()) is even, whereas (() and (pie) and ( ) is not. Below is what I've written so far. My program keeps on printing 'Enter your string' infinitely, I'm stuck with that problem right now.

```
selection = 0
def recursion():
#The line below keeps on repeating infinitely.
    myString = str(input("Enter your string: "))
    if not myString.replace('()', ''):
        print("The string is even.")
    else:
        print("The string is not even.")

while selection != 3:
    selection = int(input("Select an option: "))

    #Ignore this.
    if selection == 1:
        print("Hi")

    #This won't work.
    elif selection == 2:
        def recursion():
            recursion()
```

Comment: What's def recursion(): recursion() under your elif selection == 2.

Comment: _"My program keeps on printing 'Enter your string' infinitely"_. That's funny, when I run it it keeps printing "Select an option: " infinitely until I enter 3. Is this your most up-to-date code? I don't see how you could even reach the "Enter your string" prompt.

Comment: Based on what Kevin and I both got from running your program, It looks like to me everything works if you just take out your def recursion under elic selection ==2 : and just put recursion(). All thats left is fixing your if statements in recursion() to do what you want it to do

Answer (score 0):

This outputs the correct even/not even answers.

```
 selection = 0
 def recursion():
    myString = str(raw_input("Enter your string: "))  #Use raw_input or ( ) will be () 
    paren = 0
    for char in myString:
        if char == "(":
            paren += 1
        elif char == ")":
            paren -= 1
        else:
            print "Not Even"
            return

        if paren < 0:
            print "Not even"
            return
    if paren != 0:
        print "Not even"
        return
    print "Even"
    return

while selection != 3:
    selection = int(input("Select an option: "))

    #Ignore this.
    if selection == 1:
        print("Hi")

    #This won't work.
    elif selection == 2:
        recursion()    #This isn't a recursive function - naming it as so is...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using Python 3, you should use raw_input instead of input, because input gives back the result in whatever type matches the input best, whereas raw_input always returns a string. In Python 3, input always returns a string. Also, why are you redefining recursion? Just call it from the elif statement. Example:

```
selection = 0
def recursion():
#The line below keeps on repeating infinitely.
    myString = raw_input("Enter your string: ") # No need to convert to string.
    if not myString.replace('()', ''):
        print("The string is even.")
    else:
        print("The string is not even.")

while selection != 3:
    selection = int(raw_input("Select an option: "))

    #Ignore this.
    if selection == 1:
        print("Hi")

    #This won't work.
    elif selection == 2:
        recursion() # Just call it, as your program already
                    # recurs because of the if statement.
```